# Find solution matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble figuring out how to find solution matrices for differential equation, I hope someone can help me.

Example: 
Consider the non autonomous linear second order equation:

$$ x''-\frac{1}{t}x'-t^2 x =0$$

for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t >0$

Let $x_1 = e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$ and   $x_2 = e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2} $ be two maximal solutions til the equation above.

Write the corresponding first order system and use the two solutions given above to construct the solution matrix for the first order equation.

$y_1 = x$, $y_2 = x'$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
        y_1' \\
        y_2' \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
        x' \\
        x'' \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
        y2 \\
        t^2y_1+\frac{1}{t}y_2 \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        t^2 & \frac{1}{t} \\
\end{pmatrix} \cdot\begin{pmatrix}
        y_1 \\
        y_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We now have $y' = A(t)y$, where A(t) is the matrix \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        t^2 & \frac{1}{t} \\
\end{pmatrix}

Now I am not really sure how to proceed and find the solution matrix. Normally I would find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors,  but I cannot make it work.

Comment: Is the right hand side of the equation $=0$ ?

Comment: Whoops, my bad fixed it

Comment: You already have the solutions, you just need to insert them into the fundamental matrix $\pmatrix{x_1&x_2\\x_1'&x_2'}$. // Make sure your time variable is always $t$.